# Javascript; Accessing frameset frames from within other frames

Tags: javascript, frames

I have a system in place which uses a frameset, within the frameset frames there are some calls like;

```
top.frame1.location = "newlocation";
```

and

```
top.frame2.afunction();
```

However I am updating the system, and now the frameset resides inside an iframe, so obviously all of the top.frame.whatever calls no longer work. Now I'm trying to find a solution which doesn't involve changing the "top." in the ton of pages that run various functions.

I've tried in the top most page doing something like this;

```
frame1 = $('#containerframe').contents().find('#frame1');
```

But that doesn't seem to work, it just says top.frame1.document is undefined when trying to access the document.

Any suggestions would be cool :)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value in  `top.frame1` with a jQuery set, which is NOT the same object as the default (which is a window object) which is why you are getting the "undefined" error - a jQuery set *doesn't have* a `document` property.

If you want to fix this *without* changing all your references to top.frame1, then you have a couple choices.  Assuming `#containerframe` is your iframe, I think this will work

In your parent-most page

```
frame1 = self.frames.containerframe.frames.frame1;
```

### EDIT

The `frames` collection works off of `name` attributes, so make sure your iframe looks like this

```
<iframe id="containerframe" name="containerframe" />
```