# How to access element present inside a iframe from parent window?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe. I want to access a table which present inside iframe.I want to access it from parent window of iframe. I have written JS like

```
Document.getElementById("table Id");
```

But the result come null. What is the process to get it?
thanks

Comment: i think this is not possible nowadays, is it cross-domain?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729577/can-javascript-access-iframe-elements-from-the-parent-page

Comment: @fskreuz that only the case when the iframe isn't on the same domain. Otherwise there is no problem to access elements in the iframe.

Comment: @user1122379 you should mention if the iframe is on the same domain or not, cause the answer to the question depends a lot on that fact.

Answer (score 4):

```
x=document.getElementById("iFrameId");
x.contentDocument.getElementById("tableId");
```

if you can use jQuery i guess it will work across browsers

`$("#iFrameId").contents().find("#tableId")`

Comment: Thanks. But it is not working. Now I am thinking that I can use a div and fill that div using PHP httprequest to the url. But I dont know how to do that httpRequest. Could you provide me some example code please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the element from the iFrame's document.  Per Juan's comment, check against both the name, and id of the iFrame

```
var targetFrame = window.frames["nameOfIFrame"] || window.frames["iFrameId"];
targetFrame.document.getElementById("tableId");
```

**EDIT**

I just tested this with the following:

```
window.frames["fName"].document.getElementById("Adam").innerHTML
```

in the Chrome console, and it output the html of the `Adam` div from within my iframe.

Comment: What's wrong with it?  `window.frames["iFrameId"].document.getElementById` seems to come back as a native method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729577/can-javascript-access-iframe-elements-from-the-parent-page

Comment: @PenchoIlchev - that question deals with an iframe loading code on a **different domain** - OP never said that was the case here.  Assuming the iFrame is loading the same domain, the above code seems to work fine -- I just tested it

Comment: `frames[frameName]` is the best cross browser way to access the window object inside frames. Your example implies an ID but my experience is the you should also use the name attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644676/javascript-accessing-frameset-frames-from-within-other-frames

Comment: @JuanMendes - Thanks.  I tested it and using the name of the iFrame works splendidly.  I didn't know that was preferable to using an id, but I edited my answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis: You should use both `id` and `name` in the HTML for complete cross-browser goodness! At least that was true around three years ago with IE 7, chrome and firefox