# AJAX origin is not allowed

Tags: ajax

Having an issue with an AJAX call.  I think this big, funky function that in essence gives back a yes/now for a string.

```
usdaurl = 'http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice?eligibilityType=Property&requestString=<?xml version="1.0"?><Eligibility xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/var/lib/tomcat5/webapps/eligibility/Eligibilitywsdl.xsd"><PropertyRequest StreetAddress1="'+street+'" StreetAddress2="" StreetAddress3="" City="'+city+'" State="'+state+'" County="" Zip="'+zip+'" Program="RBS"></PropertyRequest></Eligibility>';
$.ajax({
    url: usdaurl,
    dataType: 'XML',
    success: function(xml){
        var usda = $('Property').attr('Eligibility');
    }
});
```

This is the simple version, I've drilled the problem down to this function.  This is the error I keep getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice?eligibil…%2262034%22%20Program=%22RBS%22%3E%3C/PropertyRequest%3E%3C/Eligibility%3E. 
Origin http://[mydomain ;)] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The URL that the query is trying to access works.  If I just put it in to a browser, I get back some XML.  But when I try to use AJAX, I get this error.

Comment: Doing this via ajax is bad.  Consider doing a 1px iframe.  Opening the cross site scripting door can be a slippery slope of doom.

Comment: So the source url of the 1px iframe is the URL of the AJAX call?  How do you drill down into that iframe?  Any reference links you could share?

Comment: *GASP!* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676478/how-to-access-element-present-inside-a-iframe-from-parent-window  Might this be what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is not allowed to call other domains out of the box. There are some browser specific workarounds.