# how to access the element inside iframe, from parent document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

```
function contents_nb(name, height) {
    1. document.getElementById('contents_iframe').height = height+'px';
    2. var $currentIFrame = $('#contents_iframe'); 
    3. $currentIFrame.contents().find(".wrap_contents").hide();
    4. $currentIFrame.contents().find(".greetings").fadeIn(2500);
}
```

this is my jquery syntax.

no.1 ~ 3, it works well.

but line no.4, it doesn't work.

structure of html document inside iframe is ...

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap_contents">
        <div class="greetings">
        </div>
        <div class="operational_philosophy">
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

what is the reason? what causes this problem?

and syntax of the parent html document is..

```
<iframe id="contents_iframe"></iframe>
```

what is the problem??
why can not find class inside class?

Comment: Please post normal HTML

Comment: Can you show more code, or put it on JSFiddle and include link?

Comment: Is the source of iframe is same as same as the source of the parent? If it is not so, then you can't access the iframe content normally because of the browser security policies

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access element present inside a iframe from parent window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676478/how-to-access-element-present-inside-a-iframe-from-parent-window)

Comment: every documents are in a single directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may used jquery contents() function to access/find the elements,

```
$("#iframeID").contents().find("#contentID");
```

Comment: that's what I used. but it doesn't work at the element inside element.

Comment: I have tested the same, it is working fine, I have a question,  what is the use of $currentIFrame.contents().find(".wrap_contents").hide();