# How to get an element's attribute value in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

My question may seem a already asked and answered to you, but when I searched for this question on SO I came across only the questions about getting attribute of the `<iframe>` element.
But my question is that **"How to get an element's attribute value in the iframe?"**.
For example if my iframe has an id `iframe1` and it's src is https://anonfiles.com/z7E9W640ud/anime-girls-night-sky-scenery-clouds-stars-4K-64_jpg so how can I get the  `href` value of an anchor link with an id `download-url` in that page?
The main thing, I want to put that value into an another element(most probably a video or an anchor link) with an id `linkHere`.

I prefer using Vanilla JS or Jquery for this.

Also If I made any mistakes, feel free to correct me.
**THANKS IN ADVANCE :)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to access the element inside iframe, from parent document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751631/how-to-access-the-element-inside-iframe-from-parent-document)

Comment: @cloned I don't think so, I want to use the value I get from that page into an another element.

Comment: This is then a different question. What have you tried to get the value into a different element? Where is your effort?

Answer (score 0):

html

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].getAttribute("src"); 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First of all, this is JS and not HTML, and also when providing code examples, also provide some explanation.