# Javascript, accessing nested frames in framesets from a iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frame

I'm having issues accessing a frame that is part of a page loaded into a iframe.  The frame is nested in multiple framesets.

My html looks like this:

```
<iframe name="sourceframe" src="siteindex.html">
    #document <-- this appears in the dom tree. Not sure if it's relevant.
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <frameset>
                ...other frames
                <frameset>
                    <frame name="targetframe" src="sitesubpage.html">
                        ...I want to access this frame and replace the contents with a different html page...
                    </frame>
                </frameset>
            </frameset>
        </html>
</iframe>
```

I have read similar questions none of which have a solution that I can get to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644676/javascript-accessing-frameset-frames-from-within-other-frames  I can't get method used in this answer to work when navigating the framesets.

Comment: `document.frames['sourceframe'].document.frames['targetframe']` supposed to contain a reference to the `window` of the `#targetframe`, from the page where `#sourceframe` is placed. If this is not what you need , please elaborate your question, _from where to which element / object_ you need the reference.

Comment: @Teemu that is what I need. I seem to have something setup wrong.  Checking document.frames.length from the page where my source iframe is gives 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' Should it not be 1?

Comment: Odd... Try `window` instead `document`. Which browser are you using? Also are you sure the `iframe` exists at the time you're reading the length of the `frames`? This is better to do within `window.onload` handler function.

Comment: @Teemu The iframe is created window.onload (in the head). Using chrome Version 27.0.1453.116.  window.frames['sourceFrame'].frames.length gives a length of 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
window.frames['sourceframe'].frames['targetframe'].location.href = 'new_html_page';
```

FF and Chrome have `frames` collection only in `window`, IE and Opera have it also in the `document`. The above code works (tested), when you get your timing corrected.

Try to use some timeout before changing the the `href`, or trigger the change from the `#targetframe`. Also you can attach an `onload` event listener to the `iframe`, and trigger the change in it. One more, you can place the script creating the `iframe` just before closing `body` tag, then you can use `window.onload` to change the page in the depths...

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  Sorted my timing and everything is working.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want to access the most top `frameset` from the most inner `frame`. any suggestion?. i didn't use `iframe` i just used `frameset`.

Comment: my questions details are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154947/how-to-print-all-frames-on-the-page-in-one-file/31156188#31156188 
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132368/how-to-print-all-frames-inside-frameset-nested-frameset-with-javascript?noredirect=1#comment50278240_31132368

Answer (score 0):

You could give your `frame` element with `name='targetframe'` an `id='targetframe'` and do something like:

```
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
function getChildFrame(id){
  var t = E(id);
  var f = t.contentWindow || t.contentDocument;
  if(f.document)f = f.document;
  return f;
}
var tf = getChildFrame('targetframe');
tf.style.backgroundColor = '#007';
```

See

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

and

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_frames.asp

for more details. Of course, the Same Origin Policy applies. In other words you can't access someone else's `frame`, without permission.

By the way, you can access the `frames` array with a number as well.

Comment: The issue with this is the frames have name attribues not ID's.  So I think the nested elements still need to be traversed?

Comment: @PHPglue Only `window` object can have a `parent` property.

Comment: Oops, I see and have corrected my mistake. If you want the parent window use `window.parent`.