# How to print all frames on the page in one file

Tags: javascript, printing, frame

I am using `frameset` tag and i want to print all frames inside the frame set

```
<html>
     <frameset rows="10%,*">
       <frame name="top_frame" src="top-frame.htm" frameborder="1" noresize="0" scrolling="no">
       <frameset cols="20%,*">
          <frame name="left_frame" src="left-frame.htm" frameborder="0" noresize="0" scrolling="no">
          <frame name="right_frame" src="right-frame.htm" frameborder="0" noresize="0" scrolling="auto">
       </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

I used `parent.window.focus();parent.print();` it works in Chrome, but in IE11 it prints each frame in one file.

any suggestion?

I also used `parent.window.focus();window.print();` but it doesn't work in both.

Comment: i used it, but still is not working

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
try{
    document.execCommand('print', false, null);
}
catch(e){
    window.print();
}
```

[Source link](http://bytes.com/topic/misc/answers/629926-ie7-printing-iframe-solution)

Comment: Still it prints only the top frame not the visible window